# Call wait() from a Class on other Thread

Tags: java, android

I want to call `wait()` on other Thread becoz if my current class some part of code is executing don't want to interrupt by other thread..
for this i m doing like this

main.class

```
testThread as=new testThread();
try{
    synchronized(as) {
        wait();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(tag, "In ==Scheduler== error"+e.toString());
}
```

testThread.class

```
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Thread"); 
        try {
            Thread.sleep(6000);
        } catch(Exception r) {

        }
    }
}
```

And getting the following error

> error java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()

Why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either

```
synchronized(as)
{
    as.wait();
}
```

or

```
synchronized(this)
{
    wait();
}
```

Based on what you want. You need to synchronize whatever you're waiting for.

Comment: That is because as is your monitor, and it is never being woken up with a call to `notify`

Comment: Of course, "wait" means "wait"!! You will need to wake up the waiting thread by calling "notify" on the thread object from another thread.